# Installed gmp but can't see it

Tags: c, linux, gcc, gmp

To compile my own gcc, I require [gmp](http://gmplib.org/). Therefore, I downloaded a tarball of gmp, and installed it by the usual steps of configure, make and make install. However, afterwards, I can't see any gmp in my system by typing 'which gmp'. So my question is where is gmp hidden? I am using CentOS 5.6.

### EDIT

OK, I can see the header and library files of gmp in /usr/local/include and /usr/local/lib. I used `--with-gmp-include=/usr/local/include --with-gmp-lib=/usr/local/lib` but the gcc's configure still complains about not finding gmp. What is going on here?

Comment: gmp is a library. what were you expecting from `which gmp` exactly?

Comment: Basically after installing gmp, the configure of gcc still doesn't see it. I can basically see the header file in /usr/local/include and library files in /usr/local/lib. But how do I tell gcc installer so?

Comment: Try `configure --help` and look for a gmp configuration flag. Typically, `--gmp-include-path` or something like that.

Comment: Did you run `ldconfig` after installing the gmp package? Typically `configure` scripts try to build a program using the library and if that fails, this is reported as a non-existing library. `ldconfig` rebuilds the linker database letting `ld` do its job properly.

Answer (score 2):

Try to change

> -–with-gmp=

to

> -–with-gmp-prefix=

Thanks to [doober](http://nosemaj.org/debian-gcc-4-7)

Comment: what's the explanation for this?  and you mean "to," not "on."  we change one thing "to" another.

Comment: I've edited my answer as you suggested. I don't know the reason why the second option works whereas gcc manual contains only --with-gmp= option. But -–with-gmp-prefix= worked in my case at that time.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should run ./configure script with some params:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr
```

default prefix is /usr/local

and if your system is 64-bit:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib64
```

After that 'make && make install' should install everything in proper locations.

Answer (score 1):

You're right that you need `--with-gmp-xxx` switches.

You may also need to set to set run-path to `/usr/local/lib` or wherever you install gmp if it's not in the default runtime linker locations:

```
$ export LD_RUN_PATH=/usr/local/lib
$ configure ...
$ make ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The crucial point here that is only mentioned in one passing comment (by @Mat) is that gmp **is a library**. It is not a binary. So the resource that is produced is a bunch of `libgmp*` files in `$prefix/lib`.

There is no `$prefix/bin/gmp`...